# Error Running 'magento setup:di:compile'

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I got this error while trying to run the `magento setup:di:compile` command

```
'Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/MageBig/SocialLogin/Model/Providers/Amazon.php on line 26'
```

After Reinstalling Hybrid Auth https://doc.magebig.com/martfury/extensions/#social-login

I then got the error

```
'Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/MageBig/SocialLogin/Model/Providers/Amazon.php on line 30'
```

What did I do wrong? Any Ideas?

Please Help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are trying to install library , then its like library isn't properly installed.

Comment: You should seek support from the developer you purchased the module from.